# OpenGL error GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x0500) while glewInit()

Tags: c++, opengl, enums, crash, glew

I'm new to OpenGL and try to learn OpenGL 4 by following the http://www.openglbook.com tutorial.
On page two, we create a simple triangle using shaders. But right after creating the vertex shader, the program crashes. By Debugging, I could find a OpenGL error `GL_INVALID_ENUM` (0x0500). See code below...

Unfrotunately I couldn't find any solution. Maybe you know sth?

**Edit:**

So, after searching again for `GL_INVALID_ENUM` and `glewInit()`, I found that there are already many posts on other Websites, BUT:
Most of them had some typos in their shaders and I definitely don't. On
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library
i found:

> You might still get GL_INVALID_ENUM (depending on the version of GLEW you use), but at least GLEW ignores glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)​ and gets all function pointers.

Some recommend to just ignore the error, but I still can't run the program...
Btw, could anyone of you try to run the program? If you had the same error, we'd definitely know it's not a wrong IDE/Project configuration of mine.

Specs:

```
Windows 8.1 64bit
Intel Core i7-3517U with
Intel HD4000 GPU (OpenGL 4.0.0 Support)
8 GB RAM
```

IDE:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
using MinGW Compiler
```

code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/freeglut.h>


#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "Chapter 2"

// initialization
int CurrentWidth = 800,
    CurrentHeight = 600,
    WindowHandle = 0;

// timer
unsigned FrameCount = 0;

// chapter2 buffer object.........................
GLuint VertexShaderId,
       FragmentShaderId,
       ProgramId,
       VaoId,
       VboId,
       ColorBufferId;

const GLchar *VertexShader = {
        "#version 400\n"\

        "layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
        "layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
        "out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\

        "void main(void) {\n"\
        "    gl_Position = in_Position;\n"\
        "    ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
        "}\n"
};
const GLchar *FragmentShader = {
        "#version 400\n"\

        "in vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
        "out vec4 out_Color;\n"\

        "void main(void) {\n"\
        "    out_Color = ex_Color;\n"\
        "}\n"
};
//................................chapter2 buffer object


// initialization
void Initialize(int,char*[]);
void InitWindow(int,char*[]);
void ResizeFunction(int,int);
void RenderFunction(void);

//timer
void TimerFunction(int);
void IdleFunction(void);

// chapter2 buffer object
void Cleanup(void);
void CreateVBO(void);
void DestroyVBO(void);
void CreateShaders(void);
void DestroyShaders(void);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fprintf(stdout,"Starting OpenGL programm...\n");

    Initialize(argc,argv);
    glutMainLoop();

    fprintf(stdout,"Program terminated.\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void Initialize(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GLenum GlewInitResult; //glew

    InitWindow(argc,argv);

    //glew...........
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();

    if(GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: %s\n",
                glewGetErrorString(GlewInitResult) );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //.................glew.

    fprintf(stdout,
            "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
            glGetString(GL_VERSION) );

    //chapter2 buffer objects
    CreateShaders();
    CreateVBO();



    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc,argv); // always the first function to call!!!

    glutInitContextVersion(4,0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
                  GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);

    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth,CurrentHeight);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);

    //timer
    glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
    glutTimerFunc(0,TimerFunction,0);

    //chapter2 buffer object
    glutCloseFunc(Cleanup);
}

void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height) {
    CurrentWidth = Width;
    CurrentHeight = Height;
    glViewport(0,0,CurrentWidth,CurrentHeight);
}

void RenderFunction() {
    //timer
    ++FrameCount;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //chapter2 buffer object
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

//timer.................................
void IdleFunction() {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void TimerFunction(int Value) {
    if(0 != Value) {
        char *TempString = (char*) malloc(512 + strlen(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX));

        sprintf(TempString,
                "%s: %d Frames Per Second @ %d x %d",
                WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX,
                FrameCount * 4,
                CurrentWidth,
                CurrentHeight );

        glutSetWindowTitle(TempString);
        free(TempString);
    }
    FrameCount = 0;
    glutTimerFunc(250,TimerFunction,1);
}
//...........................................timer

//chapter2 buffer object..................................
void Cleanup() {
    DestroyShaders();
    DestroyVBO();
}

void CreateVBO() {
    GLfloat Vertices[] = {
            -0.8f, -0.8f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
             0.0f,  0.8f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
             0.8f, -0.8f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLfloat Colors[] = {
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(VaoId);

    glGenBuffers(1,&VboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,4,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1,&ColorBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorBufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Colors), Colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,4,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Could not create a VBO: %s \n",
                gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void DestroyVBO() {
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ColorBufferId);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VboId);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&VaoId);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Could not destroy the VBO: %s \n",
                gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void CreateShaders() {
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    VertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderId,1,&VertexShader,NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderId);

    FragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderId,1,&FragmentShader,NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderId);

    ProgramId = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ProgramId, VertexShaderId);
        glAttachShader(ProgramId, FragmentShaderId);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramId);

    if(glIsProgram(ProgramId) != GL_TRUE) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "ERROR: This is no GL program!\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    glUseProgram(ProgramId);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Could not create the shaders: %s \n",
                gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void DestroyShaders() {
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glUseProgram(0);

    glDetachShader(ProgramId, VertexShaderId);
    glDetachShader(ProgramId, FragmentShaderId);

    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderId);

    glDeleteProgram(ProgramId);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Could not destroy the VBO: %s \n",
                gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you made sure that `ErrorCheckValue` is `GL_NO_ERROR` right before your call to `glCreateShader`?

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you very much for your immediate help.

Comment: You were right, the error results in
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();

Comment: The Thing is:
In chapter1 of the tutorial, before introducing shaders, I did already set up glew by `glewInit()` and the program worked just fine. But when I check now, after disabling the shader stuff, I get the `1280` error when I use `glewInit()`. So topic changes slightly to:
Same error `1280`, but by calling `glewInit();`

Any ideas? Thanks for all.

Comment: Always use the hexadecimal error value. OpenGL enumerates all of its constants using base-16, so in order to lookup your error code it has to be converted from base-10 to base-16. If you convert it to base-16, you get (0x0500), which you can easily find in `"gl.h"` and is associated with `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

Comment: Did you also check the `glGetError` result before your call to `glewInit`? Maybe it happens even before that.

Comment: @KristianDuske: yes, I did. The error occures definitely by calling `glewInit()`. I thought, maybe the 32bit/64bit Versions of GLEW could be the reason, but by using `glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\x64` the program doesn't even compile (can not find the functions/links to the library). So I used the `Win32` Version... But if the error really is caused by `glewInit()`, how can I correct it? Should I use an older Version of glew? Or just Import the `.h` files?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know :-(

Answer (score 5):

I could finally solve the problem:
First of all, I did severel minor changes, so I can not tell you, if it was just one change or the sum of all, what solved it.

1. delete the `glu` library.
   I had to link this library to use `gluErrorString(...)`. Replace this function with `glewGetErrorString(...)`. Now you don't need the `glu` library anymore.
2. probably the reason for the error:
   Delete `glutInitContextVersion(4,0);`. I can't tell you really why - probably `glew` doesn't support the new OpenGL 4 functions.

That's it. I hope this helps (I found the same problem on several other Websites)!
And thanks for your advices :)

Comment: glew does very welll support GL 4.x functions. The glew errour you encountered is totally harmless (but still an annoyance the just don't fix for no apparent reason). That this error goes away if you omit the `glutInitContextVersion(4,0);` is probablby due to the fact that then, you get an old-style compatibility context (profiles were just defined beginning with GL 3.2), where the query `glewInit()` does is allowed. If both this error goes away AND your program starts to work due to this, you probably use some deprecated functionality.

Comment: I can tell you why this happens. In a core profile context, `GL_EXTENSIONS` is an invalid constant to pass to `glGetString (...)`. You must use the new `glGetStringi (...)` function. GLEW does not do this by default, given a core context without being informed to use `glGetStringi (...)`, GLEW will use `glGetString (...)` and will cause GL to generate a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error. In order to get GLEW to use `glGetStringi (...)` (which you should ONLY do in an OpenGL 3.0+ context), set `glewExperimental = true;` ***before*** calling `glewInit (...)`.